# How to install VLC 3

Tags: apt, software-installation, video, ppa, vlc

I wanted to update my VLC, as there was an audio bug, I followed the guide somewhere on the internet which told me to follow these commands to install the latest VLC in ubuntu.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
sudo apt update
sudo apt install vlc qtwayland5
```

However this installed a brand-new version of VLC, which doesn't even work properly. So, I uninstalled this using `sudo apt uninstall vlc` and removed the ppa using `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily`. And when I tried to install the old version using `sudo apt install vlc` this still installed the VLC 4, which doesn't even work.
Can anybody help me install VLC 3?

Any Help Would Be Appreciated!

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: Ubuntu ((20.04))

Comment: Please provide the output of `sudo apt-cache showpkg vlc`

Comment: @Heisenberg please provide output of `which vlc` , `snap list | grep -i vlc` , `apt-cache policy vlc` , `flatpak list | grep -i vlc` .

Answer (score 1):

You have not removed the PPA. Use ppa-purge for this purpose:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:videolan/master-daily
```

This will bring [VLC 3.0.9](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/vlc) back to the system.

---

You may want to install VLC 3.0.11 from FlatHub:

```
sudo apt-get install flatpak
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
flatpak install flathub org.videolan.VLC
```

and run it with `flatpak run org.videolan.VLC`.

Comment: I did the first two commands and it still installs vlc4

Comment: The flatpak version is v3.0.11.1 (as referenced in this command: `flatpak remote-info flathub org.videolan.VLC`), so if you did as this answer poses you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Download this package:

http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/v/vlc/vlc_3.0.9.2-1_amd64.deb

Install it from the terminal by running

```
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt clean
cd ~/Downloads
sudo dpkg -i vlc_3.0.9.2-1_amd64.deb
sudo apt update
sudo apt -f install
```

Comment: Your great solution may increase the mess.